# Sharepoint 2013 reusable document template

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am currently using Sharepoint 2013 Foundation and am trying to create a Vacation/Leave request form. My first solution to the problem was creating a custom list and using Sharepoint Designer to create a workflow that emailed the users manager for approval. This was not widely accepted by my superiors.

Is it possible to have a form template(pdf for example) that allows the user to open it, fill in the required fields and have it emailed to a manager for approval, while not overwriting the blank template or having a list of request documents for everyone to see?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure can you do it with pdf. But with Word you can connect the library fields with content inside of the document (I think it is called smart field feature) this way you will have the data to route the document in workflow to correct manager. Alternatively for this kind of process most of the time I use InfoPath - but as you are on foundation this is not available for you.